# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

The os hangs on the logo screen and all the orange dots are filled. The hard drive shuts down as you cant hear it spinning.

Btw, I'm very much a noob at Ubuntu!

Comment: How many kernels are currently installed in your system?

Comment: I have no clue its just a standard Ubuntu install so I guess 1?

Comment: When you boot into ubuntu there should be an option that says Advanced, if you enter that menu then you can find the other kernels, boot using that kernel and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem mine was because of monkeying around with plymouth 
if you didn't monkeyed with plymouth then this should fix your problem

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
And modify the line :

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
It to obtain this line :

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force apm=power_off quiet splash"
Then, save, close, and back in the terminal, execute :

sudo update-grub

have a nice day :)

Comment: Now a black screen has come up saying will now halt but still i have to use the power button

Comment: Use this command to shutdown see what happends "sudo shutdown -P now

Comment: It still just stops on the Ubuntu logo I heard the hard drive switch off