# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on shutdown after package removal

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, bluetooth, shutdown

### The problem

My Ubunutu 14.04 laptop will not shutdown anymore from the command line or from the reboot button in the OS. It hangs at the shutdown screen indefinitely. This problem started a few days ago when I tried to get bluetooth working on the laptop. I uninstalled and reinstalled some bluetooth packages, the exact names of which I have lost, and I may have used the `--purge` flag on the remove which may have deleted something important. I also can't get bluetooth working but I would first like to get my laptop to shut down properly before worrying about that.

### Attempted solutions

I have tried reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` package and I have tried to update and upgrade the system thinking that I acidentally uninstalled something important. I have also tried the following to shut down the computer:

`sudo shutdown -v 0` gives me single-user mode, which I understand to be the expected behaviour of the shutdown command

However, `sudo halt` and `sudo shutdown -h now` stops at this ModemManager screen:

[image]

After many minutes the voltage retries message appears but that message also shows on boot so I doubt it's the cause of the problem.

I have read that it could be a configuration of the `acpi` setting in the grub bootloader but I've tried every possible value (off, force, pci, etc) still with no results. I just tried the answer provided here: [Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686589/ubuntu-14-04-hangs-on-shutdown)
And the native keyboard and trackpad didn't work. I had to use a usb keyboard to restart the computer.

### Info about my computer

#### Hardware

My Laptop is the Asus UX31A

```
Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

#### Software

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Had a similar problem and running janitor in ubuntu tweak solved it for me. See my answer at my question http://askubuntu.com/a/732026/124777 , might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of normal usage and hard-resetting the laptop, for whatever reason, `sudo apt-get clean` was what ended up solving the problem. I'm also having some dpkg errors now (probably related to the failed bluetooth package installations) but that clean command solved the hanging shut down.